# How to set two way binding for Image control in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a custom view `MyPhotoView` with Image. I have set image on load. Now I want to change image on continue button click. I have tried to use TwoWay Binding and set value of Binding property but image doesn't change on the click of `Continue` button.

Previous Page Button Click 
//call from ViewModel of Previous page(Get images from Gallery)

```
List<Image> currentOriginalImages = new List<Image>();
foreach (var item in _pictureSources)
{
    currentOriginalImages.Add(new Image() { Source = item });
}
var viewModel = new CropPhotoViewModel(currentOriginalImages);
```

Custom Control `MyPhotoView` that used in XAML

```
public class MyPhotoView : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CropTopLeftXProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CropTopLeftX), typeof (float), typeof (MyPhotoView), 0f, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CropTopLeftYProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CropTopLeftY), typeof (float), typeof (MyPhotoView), 0f, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CropWidthProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CropWidth), typeof (float), typeof (MyPhotoView), 0f, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CropHeightProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CropHeight), typeof (float), typeof (MyPhotoView), 0f, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty OriginalImageProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OriginalImage), typeof (Image), typeof (MyPhotoView),null,BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public float CropTopLeftX
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(CropTopLeftXProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CropTopLeftXProperty, value); }
    }

    public float CropTopLeftY
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(CropTopLeftYProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CropTopLeftYProperty, value); }
    }

    public float CropWidth
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(CropWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CropWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public float CropHeight
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(CropHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CropHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public Image OriginalImage
    {
        get { return (Image) GetValue(OriginalImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OriginalImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<local:ContentPageWithCustomBackButton
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly=MyProject"
    x:Class="MyProject.CropPhotoPage"
    Title="Upload Photo">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="icon-nav-back" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <local:MyPhotoView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 x:Name="MyPhotoView"
                                 OriginalImage="{Binding OriginalImage}"
                                 CropTopLeftX="{Binding CropTopLeftX}"
                                 CropTopLeftY="{Binding CropTopLeftY}"
                                 CropWidth="{Binding CropWidth}"
                                 CropHeight="{Binding CropHeight}" />

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,19"
                    Text="Cancel" Clicked="CancelClicked" />

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,20,19" Clicked="ContinueClicked"
                      Text="Continue" Command="{Binding ContinueCommand}" />

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</local:ContentPageWithCustomBackButton>
```

CS Page

```
public partial class CropPhotoPage : ContentPageWithCustomBackButton
{
    public CropPhotoPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = App.Locator.CropPhoto;
    }

    public CropPhotoPage(CropPhotoViewModel bindingContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext =  bindingContext;
    }

    private void CancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPhotoView.ResetCrop();
    }

    private void ContinueClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPhotoView.ApplyCrop();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public CropPhotoViewModel(List<Image> images)
{
    ContinueCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await ContinueCommandExecute());
    _images = images;
    OriginalImage = images[0];  
}
public Image OriginalImage { get; set; }
public List<Image> _images { get; set; }
public float CropTopLeftX { get; set; }
public float CropTopLeftY { get; set; }
public float CropWidth { get; set; }
public float CropHeight { get; set; }
public int CurrentImageCounter { get; set; }

private async Task ContinueCommandExecute()
{
    //crop the image
    if(CurrentImageCounter == _images.Count)
        return;
    else
    {
        var croppedImage = _cropImageService.CropImageWithRect(_images[CurrentImageCounter],
               new Rectangle(CropTopLeftX, CropTopLeftY, CropWidth, CropHeight));
        CurrentImageCounter++;

        //I want to change image here but it doesn't change even it is 2 way binding
        OriginalImage = _images[CurrentImageCounter];
        //I also want to set all 4 parameter of CropTopLeftX/Y/Width/Heigh here
    }
}
```

I have set next image to `OriginalImage` property on click `Continue` button but it doen't change. I also want to set all 4 parameter of CropTopLeftX/Y/Width/Heigh

Can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Your viewmodel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
YourViewModel : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

(...)

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName="")
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

then you need to notify all objects which are binded to your property about the fact that it's changed:

```
Image _originalImage;
public Image OriginalImage
{
    get => _originalImage;
    set
    {
         _originalImage = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

You need to call OnPropertyChanged method inside each setter of properties which you are binded to.

Comment: Hi Michal, I have noticed that when I set any other image in `OriginalImage` it comes to `set` property with new image source but it doesn't change image on my screen. Do I need to change anything in `MyPhotoView`. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change because you aren't notifying the change. You're ViewModel needs to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implement the notification on in the setter of the property.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Image originalImage;
    public Image OriginalImage
    {
        get => originalImage;
        set 
        {
            originalImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OriginalImage)); //Notify the property is changing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I just applied your code. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: @NanjiMange  Try setting the binding mode to OneWay and see if it changes.  ```{Binding OriginalImage, Mode=OneWay}```

Comment: @NanjiMange  Also, post the entire XAML (PhotoView) code so that I can see exactly what it's binding to.  I'm assuming you have the ViewModel set as the BindingContext but can't tell.

Comment: Okay, one more thing in `MyPhotoView`, I have set `public static readonly BindableProperty OriginalImageProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OriginalImage), typeof (Image), typeof (MyPhotoView),null,BindingMode.TwoWay);`. Do I need to change anything here?

Comment: You don't need that in your MyPhotoView at all because you have a ViewModel. Your view binds to the ViewModel; the dependency property you've written is for custom controls. Delete it and just use the view model. XAML knows how to bind to other UserControls / CustomControls using DependencyProperties like you've written (but you're not using it correctly or at all I don't believe) and XAML also knows how to bind to INotifyPropertyChanged which is what's in your ViewModel.

Comment: If I remove it from CustomControl, it throws error. Can you please give me example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168394/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-michael-puckett-ii).

Comment: Okay, I am waiting

Comment: @NanjiMange Wait... Can you post the XAML to the MyPhotoView.. I am mistaken; you're dependency properties are used but I'm not sure what they are doing for you.  I apologize for miss reading it. I saw it and assumed you made the properties on your custom control to bind against assuming you're ViewModel required them.  This is not the case so I'm still confused as to what you're doing but you are correct. Just given the code you've shown me those will need to be there for it to work.  I just don't know what it's supposed to be doing or why.  Post the XAML for the MyPhotoView please.

Comment: Michel, I have added full code. I think you know but let me tell you that all these images are selected from Gallery of iPhone. Please let me know if you need more information. It's almost 2 days since I am stuck for this. Please guide. The purpose is to change to next image to crop when user click on Continue.

Comment: MyPhotoView is custom control. It doesn't have XAML. It just has CS.

Comment: @NanjiMange Ok, I think we're on the same page now. I don't know what you're custom control is doing other than just binding, there's no special display of functions of it but that's ok. Maybe you're just using it for testing but either way it was confusing. In your ViewModel, back to the original answer, you need to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged to the properties. This will alert the XAML it's changed and the binding will update. However; I don't see or understand what you're expecting to update on the binding. Let me continue...

Comment: @NanjiMange If you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged properly and update the image, the crop view control should update to the new image also. The only problem is there's nothing to show it you that it's update visually on the view or even in the code behind. Just note you will not hit the ```set``` of a dependency property during binding. That' another topic just incase you were placing a breakpoint on the setter and watching. I recommend adding a label or something to visually show you the binding change. If I am confused or have confused you please let me know.